# MySQL, IF statement in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table:

**odit_docs - table**

```
id|name |regNumber|mps_id
1 |test1|123      | 1
2 |test2|124      | NULL
```

**mps - table**

```
id|name |mpsRegnomer|
1 |test1|1233       |
2 |test2|1244       |
```

**The query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `odit_docs` as od where IF(od.mps_id IS NOT NULL, SELECT mps.mpsRegnomer FROM mps where mps.id = od.mps_id, od.regNumber) = '123'
```

**The scenario:**

If column `od.mps_id` IS NOT NULL to select value from other table `mps` based on `od.mps_id` <=> `mps.id` relationship, but if column `od.mps_id` is NULL it should take column `od.regNumber` at the end I should check if returned value from this **if-else statement** is equal to some value in this case it's **123** I got error in this form of query.

In case with **id 1** it should check if value from mps table `mps.mpsRegnomer = 123`, **because od.mps_id IS NOT NULL**

In case with **id 2** it should check if `od.regNumber = 123`, **because od.mps_id IS NULL**

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: SELECT subquery **must** be enclosed in parenthesis. Also it **must** return only one row anycase (add LIMIT 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query with fixed syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM odit_docs as od 
where IF(od.mps_id IS NOT NULL, (SELECT mps.mpsRegnomer FROM mps where mps.id = od.mps_id LIMIT 1), od.regNumber) = '123';
```

This will do the same thing but I believe it will generate a better execution plan:

```
SELECT * 
FROM odit_docs as od 
LEFT JOIN mps ON mps.id = od.mps_id
WHERE (od.mps_id IS NULL and od.regNumber = '123')
      OR (mps.id = '123')
```

Here's a sqlfiddle where you can test it:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61e101/4